# Display an image from images folder if a value equals something

Tags: php, image

i have a little problem i need some help with.
i have the following echo that displays a link to a help file:

```
echo "<h2>" . popup_help('help.php?popup=1&ship_info=1&shipno=' .
     $user_ship['shipclass'], 300, 600, $user_ship['ship_name']) ;
```

The above displays a link that leads to a help file pertaining the specific ship info,
 namely it displays the ship name.

shipclass is a number ex. 400.

how can i display an image from my images folder so i can have that image printed on the page directly?

something in the lines of;

if usership = 400 echo ship.png?

ive tried something in the lines of

```
if $user_ship['shipclass'] echo ship.png;
```

without luck.

Any ideas?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: I am not completely sure what you'd like to achieve. If your identifier for a ship is a unique number, you could rename your ship images to something like ship_400.png, put those in a resources within your htdocs root and link to them direcly: echo '<img src="/images/ships/ship_'.$user_ship['shipid'].'.png" />'

Answer (score 2):

Try to write `<img>` tag in the echo.

For example :

```
echo "<img src='/public/img/mail.png'/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have path of the image then

```
//$imagepath contains the path of img and img name
echo "<img src='".$imagepath."'/>";
```

in your case its

```
echo "<img src='shops/ship.png'/>";
```

Comment: the images are stored in a folder called, ships so that would be echo "<img src='".shops/ship.png"'/>"; .....?

Comment: @Trey its `echo "<img src='shops/ship.png'/>"`